# Send a file with a PUT request using a HttpURLConnection

Tags: java, http, io, httpurlconnection

I'm trying to do something relatively simple. I need to make a simple PUT request with a file in the body in order to upload a file to a server not in my control. Here's the code I have so far:

```
connection = ((HttpURLConnection)new URL(ticket.getEndpoint()).openConnection());
connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Length", String.valueOf(getStreamFile().length()));
connection.setUseCaches(false);
connection.setDoOutput(true);

connection.connect();

outputStream = connection.getOutputStream();

streamFileInputStream = new FileInputStream(getStreamFile());
streamFileBufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(streamFileInputStream);

byte[] streamFileBytes = new byte[getBufferLength()];
int bytesRead = 0;
int totalBytesRead = 0;

while ((bytesRead = streamFileBufferedInputStream.read(streamFileBytes)) > 0) {
    outputStream.write(streamFileBytes, 0, bytesRead);
    outputStream.flush();

    totalBytesRead += bytesRead;

    notifyListenersOnProgress((double)totalBytesRead / (double)getStreamFile().length());
}

outputStream.close();

logger.debug("Wrote {} bytes of {}, ratio: {}", 
        new Object[]{totalBytesRead, getStreamFile().length(), 
            (double)totalBytesRead / (double)getStreamFile().length()});
```

I'm watching my network manager and nothing near the size of my file gets sent. In fact, I don't know if anything is being sent *at all*, but I don't see any errors thrown.

I need to be able to send this request and also measure the status of the upload synchronously, so as to be able to inform my listeners of the upload progress. How can I modify my existing example to just work™?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try setting the `content-type` param to `multipart/form-data`. [W3C forms](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4).

Comment: I'm uploading a video to Vimeo and their [official uploading guide](https://developer.vimeo.com/apis/advanced/upload#streaming-step3) tells me to make the request this way.